# Copying data from one worksheet to another at first available row and transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA and I struggle to get the code to work. I know there are many similar questions here, but I cannot find the right paste formula. I need to copy data from the worksheet "Workbook1" and paste it into the next available row in the "Workbook2" worksheet, transposed. Thank you for your help.

So far I've got:

```
Sub MoveData()

'Define variables
Dim Workbook1 As Workbook
Dim Workbook2 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim LastRow As Long

'Set and Open
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

'Copy and paste
wb.ws.Range("A1:A5").Copy
Set Workbook2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Macro\Workbook2")
Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:M & LastRow").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: try my code below, I copy the Range in Column A untill last row with data, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Your code works perfect, thanks a lot! I have one more question if you don't mind: I want to add a timestamp for when the macro was executed in column A, and then paste the data starting from column B onwards (I simply changed the paste destination to cell B, so this part is fine). Do you know how to do this? Thanks again!!

Comment: what so you mean by "timestamp" ? you want to copy column A and paste to column B and transpose ?

Comment: I mean that in addition to the code above, I want to put the date and time the macro was executed into column A of each new line. So I want to copy from column A in workbook1, paste and transpose to column B, and in addition add a timestamp in column A of workbook2.

Comment: I suggest you start a new post, with your modifed code (from this post), add a screenshot of the desired worksheet output you want to get - this will allow other users here to help you. Regarding this post, I think I've answered your post, so please mark my answer below as "Answer"

Comment: Done - thanks again!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below looks for last row in "Sheet1" in `ThisWorkbook`, copies the entire range in Column A, and then pastes it to first available row at "Sheet1" in "Workbook2.xlsm". The `Paste` method is with `PasteSpecial` , values only and Transpose.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveData()

'Define variables
Dim Workbook1 As Workbook
Dim Workbook2 As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, DestLastRow As Long

' Set wb
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

' set and open Workbook2, need to add the file extenstion (.xlsm)
Set Workbook2 = Workbooks.Open("H:\Macro\Workbook2.xlsm")

With ws
    ' find last row with data in Column A to copy
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).Copy
End With

With Workbook2.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' find last row with data in destination workbook "Workbook2.xlsm"
    DestLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    ' paste special only values, and transpose
    .Range("A" & DestLastRow).PasteSpecial xlValues, Transpose:=True
End With

End Sub
```